# Form validation exclusion for a word

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a validation to a simple form in a Rails 4.1 project. I need to reject a form submission if a text field contains a forbidden word. My other validations work but not this one. So if the user enters no value or too long of a value it is rejected and the error message is displayed.

I have it setup similarly to the edge guide (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion) but the form submit still goes through if I enter "My favorite color is red." What should I do differently?

My model:

```
class ColorEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, presence: true 
  validates :body, length: { maximum: 255 }
  validates :body, exclusion: { in: %w(red) }
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use a regex validation for format with the "without" attribute. So, if it does not match, the form can't be submitted.

```
validates :body, format: {without: /example/}
```

Other syntax

```
validates_format_of :body, without: /example/
```

More references in:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html